# Duplicate key mapping | flutter fonts

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a custom font to my flutter file, and when doing so, I am getting this error in my pubsec.yaml:

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 62, column 1: Duplicate mapping key.
   ╷
62 │ flutter:
   │ ^^^^^^^
```

This is how I am trying to pull in the font. The fonts sit in a folder off the main directory as follows - `Main directory > fonts > Avenir > *insert fonts`

```
flutter:
    fonts:
     - family: Avenir
       fonts:
         - asset: fonts/Avenir-Bold.ttf
         - asset: fonts/Avenir-Regular.ttf
```

The above looks right according to flutter docs, but apparently not.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you still getting error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep your font file like this:
main directory> assets> fonts> Avenir-Bold.ttf

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
  fonts:
    - family: Avenir
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Avenir-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Avenir-Regular.ttf
```